# Question about acceleration and velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

A canoe is drifting left toward a hungry hippo with a velocity of $7 m/s$. The canoe rider starts paddling frantically, causing the canoe to travel to the right with a constant acceleration of $6 m/s^2$. After $4$ seconds what is the velocity of the canoe?

I first re-arranged the equation for acceleration $v=at$ to see how much our velocity changed which was $24 m/s$. Then i reasoned that if He was traveling to the left at $7 m/s$ and then traveled right at $24 m/s$ his velocity after $4$ seconds of doing so have to be $-17 m/s$ since he traveled in the opposite direction, however the answer was $17 m/s$. Why was my reasoning flawed?

Answer (score 1):

Your axes might be defined such that travelling to the left implies negative velocity and travelling to the right would mean positive velocity (axis 'points' to the right).

Otherwise the question might simply want you to calculate the magnitude of the velocity, in which case you got the answer right.